# Use angular-translate for server side translation in Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-translate

I have a small web app running on NodeJs.
I use Angular-Translate for client side translations.
Some of the strings are generated by the server and are not static on the html pages/Javascript code.

For example, server will generate "Login Failed" and I would like that string will be translated to the user's language without any client side intervention, but still use same $translateProvider as the client does.